# In MAT I have Retained Heap with 0 Shallow Heap (?!?)

Tags: memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer, retained-in-memory

I'm analyzing a heap dump with Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT).

I have a line in Heap Histogram, where Objects and Shallow Heap are 0 but there is a big amount of Retained Heap.

[image]

What does it mean? Is it not assigned to an object instance but it's only a static content? Or is it a bug in MAT?

Answer (score 1):

AuthPolicy is an abstract class. As a result, there are no instances of that class. However, AuthPolicy does have some static fields [source code of AuthPolicy](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-commons-httpclient/blob/master/commons-httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/httpclient/auth/AuthPolicy.java). It does have a HashMap and ArrayList, The retained space is probably stuck in there:

```java
...
public abstract class AuthPolicy {

    private static final HashMap   SCHEMES     = new HashMap();
    private static final ArrayList SCHEME_LIST = new ArrayList();
...
```